# Python Interpolating Time

Tags: python, interpolation

Novice in python so I hope I am asking correctly.

I have a huge set of data that I would like to interpolate to every one second and fill in the gaps with the appropriate latitude and longitude provided:

```
  Lat     Long    Time
-87.10   30.42    16:38:49
                      .
                      .
                      .
-87.09   30.40    16:39:22
                      .
                      .
                      .
-87.08   30.40    16:39:30
```

So I would like to generate a new latitude and longitude every second.

I have already plotted the corresponding latitude and longitude and would like to fill in the gaps with the interpolated data with points possibly.

Comment: Which part specifically are you having trouble with? Figuring out the missing timestamps? Interpolating between two points? etc?

Comment: Is there a way to generate the missing time in between? So between 16:38:49 and 16:39:22 there should be 34 more points. And then interpolating what the lat and long should be at each point.

Answer (score 0):

If linear interpolation is good enough for you, you can use the `numpy.interp` function with the time array that you want to use for interpolation and the time and longitude/latitude data points that are read from the input file (the time must be increasing so you may need to sort the data).

To read the data for the file you can use the `numpy.loadtxt` function adding a converter to transform the time to an increasing number:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.dates import strpdate2num

lon, lat, time = np.loadtxt('data.txt', skiprows=1,
        converters={2:strpdate2num('%H:%M:%S')}, unpack=True)
```

Then you can interpolate the longitude and latitude values using the interp function. The last argument to the linspace function gives the number of points in the time interpolated data.

```
interp_time = np.linspace(time[0], time[-1], 100)
interp_lon = np.interp(interp_time, time, lon)
interp_lat = np.interp(interp_time, time, lat)
```

For something more complicated that linear interpolation there are several facilities in `scipy.interpolation`.

Comment: Thanks Miguel, I will take a look at the example and see if I can figure it out. I have the time now as the third column, do I need to have that in a separate CSV file? Also, my data (lat/Long) is not in any ascending or descending order, they are plots from a flight path and they over lap as they back track. Will that be a huge problem?

Comment: It should be fine to have all the data in the same file. I will add an example to the answer.

Comment: I'm a little confused on:
lon, lat, time = np.loadtxt('data.txt', 
        converters={2:strpdate2num('%H:%M:%S')}, unpack=True

You are setting lon, lat, time = to that statement?

Comment: It reads the data from data.txt to three arrays corresponding to each column. The converter function converts the time to a number.

Comment: I am receiving an IndexError: list assignment index out of range

x, y, time = np.loadtxt('12cch01_new.csv', converters={2:strpdate2num('%H:%M:%S')}, unpack=True)
timeinterp = np.linspace(time[0], time[-1], 100)
xinterp = np.interp(timeinterp, time, x)
yinterp = np.interp(timeinterp, time, y)

Comment: IndexError Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\kyee\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\App\appdata\canopy-1.4.1.1975.win-x86_64\lib\site-packages\IPython\utils\py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, glob, loc)
    195 else:
    196 filename = fname
--> 197 exec compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec') in glob, loc
    198 else:
    199 def execfile(fname, *where):

C:\Users\kyee\Desktop\St_Petersburg\Cruise_799\Navigation\Interpolate.py in <module>()
     16

Comment: 17 #Interpolate
---> 18 x, y, time = np.loadtxt('12cch01_new.csv', converters={2:strpdate2num('%H:%M:%S')}, unpack=True)
     19 timeinterp = np.linspace(time[0], time[-1], 100)
     20 xinterp = np.interp(timeinterp, time, x)

C:\Users\kyee\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.pyc in loadtxt(fname, dtype, comments, delimiter, converters, skiprows, usecols, unpack, ndmin)
    829 # Unused converter specified
    830 continue
--> 831 converters[i] = conv
    832 
    833 # Parse each line, including the first

IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Comment: I think that you need the `skiprows=1` option for loadtxt to skip the header.

Comment: Does it matter where in the arguement it is placed?
x, y, time = np.loadtxt('12cch01_new.csv', converters={2:strpdate2num('%H:%M:%S')}, skiprows=[1], unpack=True)

Comment: skiprows should be an integer value. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Perhaps some line in the data file is malformatted. Try using a smaller input file with a few line to check that it works.

Comment: @MigueldeVal-Borro I am having similar type of [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412863/interpolation-of-a-value-with-a-corresponding-timestamp) with interpolation, could you please help me?